# why i am getting error while placing the order in magento

Tags: magento-1.9, sales-order, order-status

I am Getting the Error While Placing The Order. [image]

what i have to do for this?how can i place order sucessfully?

Comment: Try this [Google Search results](https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=8B_tVcW6ILGt8wfxi774Ag&gws_rd=ssl#q=there+was+an+error+processing+your+order+magento)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check your exception.log and system.log in /var/log, as well as possible /var/report entries for errors. These errors are often linked to integrated payment services. Thus, please check if your payment integrations create separate log files, e.g. check in /var/log.

Comment: Did you come to a solution? If yes please mark the answer as accepted. If not feel free to post back.